# Products randomly disappearing

Tags: magento2.3

So we seem to have a very strange issue where certain Simple products are disappearing from the front end. Running `bin/magento indexer:reindex` doesn't seem to solve anything, the only solution we've found is to manually re-save the product (making no changes)

Trying to get to the bottom of this I've started to try and compare the data in the database, before and after save. The only issue is I'm not sure what tables I should be looking at?

I have found one different between before and after saving (product not showing and then showing)

`SELECT * FROM magento.cataloginventory_stock_item where product_id = 1787`

Outputs
`item_id,product_id,stock_id,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,low_stock_date,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,website_id 1946,1787,1,8.0000,0.0000,1,0,1,0,1.0000,0,2.0000,0,1,NULL,1.0000,1,1,0,0,1,0.0000,1,0,0,0`

Has `qty_increments` = `0.0000` before save and then `1.0000` after save. However changing this value manually doesn't seem to have any effect

If anyone could help why this be happening or help with the debugging process it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to upgrading Magento version via git or others. Also, it is known as Magento 2.1.3/2.1.4/2.1.5 issue.

This is the accurate solution.

We can easily add these two files on the original Modules folder.

```
app\code\Modules\Catalog\etc\di.xml

    <?xml version=""1.0""?>
    <config xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=""urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"">
    <preference for=""Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full"" type=""Modules\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full"" />
    </config>
    
    app\code\Modules\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full.php
    
    <?php 
    namespace Modules\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action;
    
    /**
     * Class AbstractAction
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
    */
    
    class Full extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full {
    
        public function isRangingNeeded() {
            return false; // It was ""True"" as default setting.
        }
    }
```

Then, we should run this command.

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento indexer:reindex